# Erro ao se conectar com banco SQLServer C# Web.config

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, web.config, connectionstring

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação `.NET MVC`, porem quando eu vou me conectar ao banco está dando o seguinte erro:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in GerarXML.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

O meu `Web.config` está com todos os caminhos certos, olhem como está a `string` de conexao

> `add name="EfDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.230.14;Initial Catalog=db_nfe;User ID=**;Password=******" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

E o meu `controller` está assim

```
public SqlConnection sqlConn = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                       .ConnectionStrings["connectionStrings"]
                         .ConnectionString);
```

E o unico metodo que usa o banco está assim

```
private string ConsultaChaveXML(string chaves)
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    string sql = $@"SELECT * FROM db_nfe..nota_fiscal_empresa
            WHERE chave_acesso = '{chaves}'";

    SqlCommand selectChave = new SqlCommand(sql);
    //Campo do xml = dsc_xml_nota_fiscal
    SqlDataReader retornoSelect = selectChave.ExecuteReader();

    return retornoSelect["dsc_xml_nota_fiscal"].ToString();
}
private XDocument CriarXML(string xml, string chave)
{
    var xmlFile = new XDocument("root", xml);
    return xmlFile;
}
```

Comment: acho que você não passou a conexão para o `SqlCommand`?

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso e não deu certo

Comment: Qual linha dá o erro?

Comment: public SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStrings"].ConnectionString);

Comment: O erro:
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
  Source=GerarXML
  StackTrace:
       em GerarXML.Controllers.HomeController..ctor() na c:\users\filipe.silva\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GerarXML\GerarXML\Controllers\HomeController.cs:linha 17
  InnerException:

Comment: Esse metodo gerarXML é esse
private XDocument CriarXML(string xml, string chave)
        {
            var xmlFile = new XDocument("root", xml);
            return xmlFile;
        }

Comment: olha só .`ConnectionStrings["connectionStrings"]` não deveria ser `.ConnectionStrings["EfDbContext"]`?

Comment: Isso msm man, tem como vc colocar isso na resposta?

Vc é Top, vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua `ConnectionString` está com o nome da chave **errado**:

***troque:***

```
public SqlConnection sqlConn = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                       .ConnectionStrings["connectionStrings"]
                         .ConnectionString);
```

***por isso:***

```
public SqlConnection sqlConn = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                       .ConnectionStrings["EfDbContext"]
                         .ConnectionString);
```